# TypeError: articles.map is not a function using react redux

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I'm trying to fetch data from server using below method :

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
console.log("--->Find All: \n" + JSON.stringify(articles, null, 4));
res.end(JSON.stringify(articles, null, 4));  };
```

And here is my action code :

```
export const getArticles =()=> dispatch =>{
dispatch(ArticlesLoading());
fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/articles/')
.then(handleErrors)
.then(res => dispatch(
    {
        type : GET_ARTICLES,
        payload: res.json()
    }
))
    }
```

When I set initial state I can see my articles but when i want to read data from server it face with error "TypeError: articles.map is not a function". I logged my action.payload and the result is like below picture :

[image: consolelog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const getArticles =()=> dispatch => {
   dispatch(ArticlesLoading());
   fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/articles/')
       .then(handleErrors)
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(res => dispatch({
            type : GET_ARTICLES,
            payload: res,
       });
}
```

res.json return a promise, try this code instead